# Putting interactive marker in google map API

Tags: google-maps, phpmyadmin

I want to put a map in a web page where users will be able to put interactive marker (location pins) as many as they want. Now, whenever a marker is placed, I want to store that specified marker's lat, long value to be saved in a database that I have in my server (phpmyadmin).

Trying to get started with Google Map Data API. Have seen lots of examples but could not find any where interactive markers can be placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show you how to do it with [v3 of the APi](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/)

- Create your map... I'll assume you've got this part down.
- Add an event listener to the map. This event listener will call a function that will create the marker (in this case add_marker). You can use any event you want, this uses the click event.

---

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', add_marker);
```

---

- Create the function that adds the marker to the db then the map. This will require some AJAX. You use the event.latLng to get the lat/lng

---

```
function add_marker( event ) {
    lat = event.latLng.lat;
    lng = event.latLng.lng;
    // ajax code here that posts the lat/lng to the server
    // only call the remaining code to add the marker if it was successful
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map // put the handle of your map here
    });
}
```